# create space between div for smaller screens

Tags: html, css

i've been struggling to make space between the div in the smaller screens. i tried use `padding-top`, but it didn't work for me.

this is my html page

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <a href="" class="box">
                    <img src="" class="img-card-content center-block img-responsive" style="width: 200px"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <a href="" class="box">
                    <img src="" class="img-card-content center-block img-responsive" style="width: 200px"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

for my css :

```
.box {
    padding: 40px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #575757;
}
```

the rest of css is from bootstrap.

does anyone have solution for this?

Comment: Provide CSS as well.

Comment: @snkv updated sir

Comment: Just posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add following CSS for this

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .box {
        margin-bottom: 10px; /* Or required space */
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add `display:block;` to your `.box` CSS it will work

Comment: it's "media" super user :)

Comment: @SuperUser i think chrome doesn't recognize my changed css, i will mark ur answer asap :)

Answer (score 1):

> Hope this will help .. below is the working snippet :

```css
.box {
    padding: 40px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #575757;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
.box { margin-bottom:15px; display:block;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <a href="" class="box">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="img-card-content center-block img-responsive" style="width: 200px"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <a href="" class="box">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="img-card-content center-block img-responsive" style="width: 200px"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's workss ! thankyou sir, but other use already answered first. really appreciated ur answer :)

Answer (score 1):

@superuser is correct but he misspelled

```
 @media (max-width:768px) {
    .box {
        margin-bottom: 10px; /* Or required space */
        display: block;
    }
}
```